# Why can't I change my input value in React even with the onChange listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, onchange

I am quite new to React and after going through some tutorials, I was trying the below code of mine.

I made one component, passed props to it from a store, on `componentWillMount` I make a new state for component. Rendering is fine till now.

Next I bound my `state` to value of an input box and I have `onChange` listener as well. Still, I can't change my values in the field.

Since, I am from Angular background, I am assuming binding input's value to state like below will automatically update the property `name` in `state` object. Am I wrong here?

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
        updatable : false,
        name : this.props.name,
        status : this.props.status
    });
}

//relevant DOM from component's render function
<input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.name} id={'todoName' + this.props.id} onChange={this.onTodoChange.bind(this)}/>

onTodoChange(){
    console.log(this);
    //consoling 'this' here, shows old values only.
    //not sure how and even if I need to update state here.
    // Do I need to pass new state to this function from DOM
    //TODO: send new data to store
}
```

My `onTodoChange` function console the value of `this` which has same value of state as while initializing. How do I go about changing state by typing in input boxes, so that I can send them to the stores?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Unlike in the case of Angular, in React.js you need to update the state manually. You can do something like this:

```
<input
    id={'todoName' + this.props.id}
    className="form-control"
    type="text"
    value={this.state.name}
    onChange={e => this.onTodoChange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

And then in the function:

```
onTodoChange(value){
        this.setState({
             name: value
        });
    }
```

Also, you can set the initial state in the constructor of the component:

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        updatable: false,
        name: props.name,
        status: props.status
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanx...I am assuming constructor receives `props` by default. Correct??

Comment: Correct. Do remember to call super( props );

Comment: Why is the case? Is there a source for this behavior and its reason?

Answer (score 30):

You can do shortcut via inline function if you want to simply change the state variable without declaring a new function at top:

```
<input type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })}/>
```

Answer (score 22):

With the `defaultValue` prop in input, you can set a default value like fetch API and put data on input.

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={value} />
```

reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to handle multiple inputs with one handler take a look at my approach where I'm using `computed property` to get value of the input based on it's name.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john.doe@test.com"
  });

  // We need to spread the previous state and change the one we're targeting, so other data cannot be lost.
  const handleChange = e => {
    setState(prevState => {
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="name"
        name="name"
        value={state.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        className="email"
        name="email"
        value={state.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This approach will delete all attributes except for the one which was just modified, see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sammet-jyp6r
One could use `setState(state => ({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))`

Comment: MaximilianPeters is right. Just a note for React <16, the example will fail because of [React's event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html). `name` and `value` should be assign to local variables outside the `setState` updater function.

Comment: for readers confused by the above comments: You can ignore the old comments. someone fixed this by editing the spread operator (...) into the answer's code, so it works fine now without deleting all attributes. but the problem still applies to all other answers here as far as i can see

Answer (score 6):

I think it is best way for you.

You should add this: `this.onTodoChange = this.onTodoChange.bind(this)`.

And your function has event `param(e)`, and get value:

```
componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            updatable : false,
            name : this.props.name,
            status : this.props.status
        });
    this.onTodoChange = this.onTodoChange.bind(this)
    }
    
    
<input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.name} id={'todoName' + this.props.id} onChange={this.onTodoChange}/>

onTodoChange(e){
         const {name, value} = e.target;
        this.setState({[name]: value});
   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In React, the component will re-render (or update) only if the state or the prop changes.

In your case you have to update the state immediately after the change so that the component will re-render with the updates state value.

```
onTodoChange(event) {
        // update the state
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In react, state will not change until you do it by using `this.setState({});`.
That is why your console message showing old values.