# Select value doesn't change when the selected option is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I need a scroll-down bar to select different options, and while any option is selected, its value should appear in the bar. Now the problem is, the value doesn't change according to the selection:

```
const [stateSelected, setStateSelected] = useState('')

const stateChange = e => {
  setStateSelected(e.target.value)
}

var states = statepicker.getStates('us');

return (
  <select className="settings__inputSelect" onChange={stateChange} value={''}>
    <option value={""} disabled={true}>Select State</option>
      {states.map(state => (
        <option value={state} name="state">{state}</option>
      ))}
  </select>
);
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Please put it in the answer and let me reward you

Comment: That's very kind, but I'm convinced this has been asked before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I change my input value in React even with the onChange listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736213/why-cant-i-change-my-input-value-in-react-even-with-the-onchange-listener)

Comment: [Other related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+select+doesn%27t+change+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ALeKk014YeY5UBvBD0pa59mElqbZxy5E3w:1623082839304&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-k8_g9oXxAhXLAZ0JHdpfDScQrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1680&bih=907)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const [stateSelected, setStateSelected] = useState('');

const stateChange = e => {
  setStateSelected(e.target.value)
}

var states = statepicker.getStates('us');

return (
  <select className="settings__inputSelect" onChange={stateChange} value={stateSelected}>
    <option value={""} disabled={true}>Select State</option>
      {states.map(state => (
        <option value={state} name="state">{state}</option>
      ))}
  </select>
);
```